# How to fix "Calling GetProcAddress on ISAPI filter "C\..\php5.dll" failed" error in iis?

Tags: iis, fastcgi

The error follows

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Calling GetProcAddress on ISAPI filter "C:..\php5.dll" failed

in iis when try to run a php website

How to fix this?

Comment: What was this? Asked a question and answered the same in next minute!!! Miracle happens :)

Comment: @Aditya I just asked to share the answer :P

Comment: :) Just kidding, plz dont take this as any offense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the following in commmand prompt

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe set config -section:isapiCgiRestriction /
+[path='C:\php\php5.dll',allowed='true']
```

Comment: The term 'C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...